# Twilio Stream stop working after call update iterations

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio Programmable Voice, using  tag to stream the call audio to my server, and then update the call using nodejs SDK.

```
client.calls(_this.CallSid).update
({twiml:
`<Response>
<Play>${url}</Play>
<Start>
<Stream url="${_this.dnsUrl}">
<Parameter name="dnsUrl" value="${_this.dnsUrl}"/>
</Stream>
</Start>
<Pause length="15"/>
</Response>`
})
```

Everything works smoothly until after 5 iterations or around 50 seconds, Twilio updates the call but the websocket connection stops working. I am pretty sure the server is up and running and not at full capacity.

Any ideas of why this happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds to me like you are setting up 5+ websocket streams of the same call to be sent to your server? If so, you should likely look into [stopping a stream](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/stream#stopping-a-stream) before starting another one. Or only starting and using one stream.

It also seems that the use case behind this is possible speech recognition in response to a message that you are `<Play>`ing to the end user? If that is the case, have you considered using [`<Gather>` with `input="speech"`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#attributes-input) instead? That way you would receive the recognised speech as text in the webhook callback and you can drive the whole call through TwiML instead of having to update the call with the REST API.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct. I was setting up 5+ websocket streams. It would be great if you can add this in the documentation (at least I was not able to see that). Using <Start><Stream> in the first twinMl will maintain the stream open during the call, no matter if you update it or not.